# how to replace duplicated string using re{n,} in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want change "aaa" or "aa..." to "." using `Regex(re{2,})`

Below is my code

```
    var answer = "aaa"
    var re = Regex("re{2,}a") // Regex("are{2,}")
    answer = re.replace(answer,".")
    println(answer)
```

`Regex("re{2,}a")` and `Regex("are{2,}")`

Both println `aaa`

How can I replace duplicated string using re{n,} ??

Comment: What means _"aa..." to "."_?
You want any duplicate character to be replaced with ".", and it should be done iteratively until there will be no duplicatres? Like on 1st iteration "aa" is replaced with "." and "..." is replaced with ".", so result of iteration is "..", which is afterwards replaced with "."?

Or `aa...` is just a notation for bunch of `a` characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var tests = arrayOf("a","aa","aaa","aaaa")
    val re = Regex("a(a+)")
    tests.forEach {t->
        val result = re.replace(t,".")
        println(result)
    }
}
```

output:

a
.
.
.

Comment: thank you! Umm.. then if i want to . to a how can I do that? . mean all character...

Comment: ah using //. I got it

Comment: not sure i understand you ? did the problem solve?

Comment: great! so please mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Generic regex to replace any duplicates (not only duplicate `a` symbols) is [`(?<symbol>.)\k<symbol>+`](https://regex101.com/r/bt9jzG/1/)

You may define an extension function for convenient usage:

```kotlin
private val duplicateRegex = "(?<symbol>.)\\k<symbol>+".toRegex()
fun String.replaceDuplicatesWith(replacement: String): String = replace(duplicateRegex, replacement)
```

Usage:

```kotlin
println("a".replaceDuplicatesWith("."))     //a
println("aaa".replaceDuplicatesWith("."))   //.
println("aa...".replaceDuplicatesWith(".")) //..
```

If you want duplicates to be iteratively replaced (like `"aa..."` -> `".."` -> `"."`) you'll need an auxilary recursive method:

```
tailrec fun String.iterativelyReplaceDuplicatesWith(replacement: String): String {
    val result = this.replaceDuplicatesWith(replacement)
    return if (result == this) result else result.iterativelyReplaceDuplicatesWith(replacement)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
println("a".iterativelyReplaceDuplicatesWith("."))     //a
println("aaa".iterativelyReplaceDuplicatesWith("."))   //.
println("aa...".iterativelyReplaceDuplicatesWith(".")) //.
```